# Running program and providing input from shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script as follows

```
ln -s -f /ctf/message/dave.inbox /home/alice/imoprt.inbox
/ctf/message/sendmsg
echo hello
```

The purpose of the script is to first make a link, then run a program, and provide hello as input to the program. It all works except providing hello as the input. I can do this easily by writing a script just like

> echo hello

but then I am unable to do some other things, such as linking before. Is there a way to do this sequence of commands?

Comment: Are you trying to do `echo hello | /ctf/message/sendmsg`?

Comment: What if I want to do a series of input? Like multiple inputs to the program one after the other

Comment: feed it all the input you want.  Perhaps you'll want to use a heredoc to give multi-line input, but you can also do `printf 'line1\nline2\n' | sendmsg`.  It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Or, you may want to create a fifo and run `sendmsg` asynchronously  and then let the script continue, feeding data to the program through the fifo.

Comment: @Ben - I think more details of just what you want to do are needed.  Based on your comment, it sounds like you need some form of loop.

Comment: @ash the program just takes some basic user input- it might look like the following
./sendmsg
[input] Alice
[input] 2
[input] 4
Im wondering if theres a way I can run the program and automatically pass these in through my script

Comment: @WilliamPursell to pass in multiple inputs I have tried echo alice; echo 2; echo 4 | ./sendmsg- now this unfortunately does not do quite what I want it to, it just does the two echos and passes the final as input. I will have a go at some of your other methods

Comment: Use brackets: `{ echo alice; echo 2; echo 4; } | sendmsg`

Comment: @Ben : It's a bit pointless if you put this supplemental information into a comment, if it is relevant for answering the question. Edit your question and put everything into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few common ways to provide input to a command:

```
echo input | cmd
```

```
{ echo one; echo two; echo three; } | cmd
```

```
cmd <<EOF
line 1 of input 
line 2 of input
EOF
```

```
trap 'rm -f fifo' 0
mkfifo fifo
cmd < fifo &
{
echo line 1 of input
var=$( echo line 2 of input generated dynamically )
echo "$var"
echo another line of input
} > fifo
wait
```

Comment: Great for the use of `mkfifo`, but the heredoc version could be simpler written without a pipe, using just `cmd <<EOF`.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you.  It is amazing!  Even after decades of railing against UUOC how easy it is to fall into it.